# How do different Services share one network connection?

Tags: android, service, tcp, push-notification, ipc

I'am developing something like a Push Notification SDK, when users integrate the SDK to their application, the SDK create a Service and receive Notifications through a TCP connection.

Now here is the question: Assume that many applications will use the SDK on the some android device, all of the application need to receive their own notifications, if we create TCP connection in each Service, it will cost too much resources and battery power, so I want to use a main Service(maybe the first Service start by SDK) to set up TCP connection, the other Services reuse the connection by some kind of IPC. But I don't known what kind of techniques is best to use.

Is there anyone who can give some advice?

thanks~

Comment: Some developers are already uncomfortable with push messages coming through a Google-supplied process, like happens with GCM. What you are proposing is to allow all of your push messages to be in a random process of a random app written by a random developer. Many will conisider this to be significantly worse from a security standpoint.

Comment: Thanks. Its there some way to communicate across Services and provide a synchronization mechanism like Lock and Semaphore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem this way:

Make a public Service(android:export="true") to set up TCP connection to the server, when the APP starts, first check if the public Service exists, if not, call startService(). Then call bindService() in the APP. To communication with the public Service, use a Messenger class:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger